# Alternative to Parthasarathy's "Probability measures on metric spaces"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the book "Probability measures on metric spaces" by K. R. Parthasarathy the fifth chapter is devoted to the Kolmogorov consistency theorem. Before coming to this result, however, he proves the following:

Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a Borel space and $\mathcal{B}_n\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ a $\sigma$-algebra such that

(i) $\mathcal{B}_1\subseteq\mathcal{B}_2\subseteq ...$ and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}\mathcal{B}_n$ generates $\mathcal{B}$.

(ii) $(X,\mathcal{B}_n)$ is a standard Borel space for each $n=1,2,...$

Then, in order that every consistent sequence of measures on $\mathcal{B_1},\mathcal{B}_2,...$ be extendable to a measure on $\mathcal{B}$ it is necessary and sufficient that $\displaystyle\bigcup_n A_n\neq\emptyset$ for each sequence $A_1,A_2,...$. If this is the case, then $(X,\mathcal{B})$ is also standard.

I need this theorem in order to prove a different result, and I would like for my text to be somewhat self-contained. The problem is, however, that this would mean adding quite a large appendix if I were to follow the lines of the Parthasarathy book. Hence, my question is: Does anyone know of an alternative text containing a different proof of this (or a similar) result?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Donald Cohn's proof: Theorem 10.6.2 in his textbook Measure Theory (2ed.), Birkh\"auser 2013. Note: the first edition does not contain a proof!